# Unable to ssh openstack running instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am unable to SSH with my key-pair for running openstack instance. Tried soft/hard reboot but still the instance is unresponsive. Is there any way I can SSH this instance ?

Comment: Does "unable" mean that there is some error message involved?

Comment: While I am trying to access it using putty. I am getting connection refused, but I am able to ping the server.

Comment: @VishalBhosale, did you look into the security group you are using? If there is no rule to allow ssh connection, then vrouter will drop your ssh packets.

Comment: Actually I was able to ssh it multiple times using the same security group, but after 5 -6 days of creation it has become unresponsive.

Comment: If you are sure, the security group hasn't changed, then you can start ssh and tcpdump in vrouter to check if there is any problem

Comment: Some of the points that you can recheck are: 1: Key-pair being used 2: username and default password of the booted VM 3: Is ssh server pre-configured in the newly spawned VM

Comment: @abhilash_goyal Yes i tried to change Key-pair but it didn't worked. Also username by default is ubuntu.. and we can access only using keypair so no need of password. Also openssh is pre-configured while it get spawned.

Comment: @VishalBhosale: can you please share the output of SSH 'ssh -i <path/to/file.pem> -vvv ubuntu@<hostname>' in verbose mode, if it can put some more light on the issue?

Comment: @sauumum ubuntu@postgresql-salt-master:~$ ssh -i vishalb_proj.pem -vvv ubuntu@10.20.21.103
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.20.21.103" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.20.21.103 [10.20.21.103] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.20.21.103 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.20.21.103 port 22: Connection timed out
ubuntu@postgresql-salt-master:~$

Answer (score 1):

As you are unable to do `ssh` to the instance:

Please check the `security group rules`, whether you have enabled `port 22`.

Comment: I checked the security Group rules.. and port allowed is mentioned as Any. So I think I am good at that side.

Comment: ALLOW IPv4 from default
ALLOW IPv4 to 0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW IPv6 from default
ALLOW IPv6 to ::/0